# Detecting human body from video source in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, video-processing, image-recognition, aforge

I am trying to extract human from a video source, so that I can use his image later. I need to only extract human body, and ignore the environment. The good thing is that the background is static. I have tried to use AForge and applied CustomFrameDifferenceDetector filter, which compares current frame to the static background image and extracts the pixels which differ (difference>threshold). It works well, but there is a problem when skin or part of the clothing has the similar color to background. In these cases filter ignores these parts and the result has various holes in the body. Simply decreasing threshold doesn't solve the problem, since body shadows and other noise increases (even under noise supression).

Do you know of any known solution to this problem? Or is it still unsolved problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hard to solve issue (and one of the reasons for Microsoft's Kinect to not use visible light only and why blue/green screening is still so popular). I'd try to remove holes (you should be able to predict where the body has to be). If you've got the processing power, use different thresholds and merge the results. You could as well try to filter new separated images (e.g. add current frame to last frame and normalize the result). This way you could track shapes you're losing for one frame a lot more consistent.

A different approach: Use the detected shape/region for detecting the position of the body only. I.e. ignore its specific shape and use a premade shapre above/around the estimated body position. This most likely won't work if you'd like to do some kind of bluescreen like behaviour but it might help as well closing holes.

Answer (score 1):

[Alturos.Yolo](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.Yolo) does exactly what you are looking for.

Yolo learns from annotated images how to detect the objects you are looking for. First you need to install the project, along with a set of already trained images using the Nuget Package Manager. In your case the YOLOv2-tiny model should suffice:

```
Install-Package Alturos.Yolo
Install-Package Alturos.YoloV2TinyVocData
```

Once installed, you can use it like this to detect a human in your image:

```
using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper("yolov2-tiny-voc.cfg", "yolov2-tiny-voc.weights", "voc.names"))
{
    var items = yoloWrapper.Detect(@"your_image.jpg");
    //if (items[0].Type == "Person") { ... }
}
```

The items array will contain information about all the objects found. You can check there if it's a human you are looking at, using the Type property.